# how to implement openstack swift API in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, openstack-swift

I am trying to add openstack-SDK-DotNet reference in my windows phone 8.1 project but it throw error-
**Could not install package 'OpenStack-SDK-DotNet 0.9.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1'**

Please help me how to add openstack-SDK-DotNet reference in my windows phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 universal project.

Comment: i think its available upto WIndows phone 8 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have established openstack swift connection with windows phone 8.1 after these steps:
1. Add newtonsoft.json version - 6.0.2 into your project.
2. then Add openstack-sdk-dotnot reference.
3. After add these reference use this code "**openstack swift dotnet api support upto v2.0 only,so keep in mind**"

```
        try
        {
        var authUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/v2.0");
        var userName = "xxx";
        var password = "xxx";
       // var tenantId = "xxx..xxx";
        var tenantName = "xxx";
        var credential = new OpenStackCredential(authUri, userName, password, tenantName, "Region");
        var client = OpenStackClientFactory.CreateClient(credential);


            await client.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var ex = exception;
        }

        var storageServiceClient = client.CreateServiceClient<IStorageServiceClient>();
        var storageAccount = await storageServiceClient.GetStorageAccount();

        foreach (var container in storageAccount.Containers)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine(container.Name);
        }
```